# c# destructors (or finalisers?) called automatically at the end of my program - should I do somthing about that?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, finalizer

So I have been reading loads of posts regarding how to deal with memory allocation and finalisers etc... I think I am clear on it, until I saw the debug that I get from running my program. The program itself is on a secure network and my "internet access" PC does not have C# so the un-tested example below may not give exactly the same behaviour, but hopefully serves to show what I am seeing:

I have two files:

**cli.cs**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("------ ITERATION " + i + "------");
    Regression.Tests.FileOperations.runTest();
}
Console.WriteLine("Test Finished");
```

**FileOperations.cs**

```
class FileOperations
{
    Obj1 obj1 = null;
    Obj2 obj2 = null;

    public void doStuff()
    {
        // Clear the objects
        obj1 = null;
        obj2 = null;

        // Create the objects
        obj1 = new Obj1();
        obj2 = new Obj2();

        // do stuff (in this case just sleep for 5 seconds)
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    // Static function so its can be called without instance
    static public void runTest()
    {
        FileOperations fileOps = new FileOperations();
        fileOps.doStuff();
    }
}
```

- So in cli.cs we call the static function runTest() in a loop which
  iterates 3 times.
- runTest() instantiates a FileOperations object and
  then calls its doStuff() function.
- doStuff() Clears any previous objects by setting them to null (I read this is the way to do that). Then it creates new instances of the objects for use.

So I tested this and it all seems to work ok. However the output to my program gives me this debug:

```
------ ITERATION 1 ------
------ ITERATION 2 ------
------ ITERATION 3 ------
Test Finished
~Obj1()
~Obj2()
~Obj1()
~Obj2()
~Obj1()
~Obj2()
```

So, if I am clearing the objects correctly (which I may not be?) why are all my Obj1 and Obj2's only getting deleted at the end of the programs? - maybe this is correct? - I have not managed to find any examples of people with the same output...

Comment: Setting your objects to null and afterwards setting them to something different is pointless. The moment you assign another instance to your variable and the previous one doen´t have any other references it will be garbage-collected automatically, no need to do this on your own unless you have some un-managed ressources (e.g. file-readers). The reason you see this output is that your program finishes to fast, making it impossible to determine when *exactly* the GC kicks in - it´s only guaranateed to work early enough.

Comment: @HimBromBeere ah ok, that is good to know! : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have only three iterations, so there aren´t many point in time in your program when Garabage-Collection may take place. So even if GC would kick in *three times* (which I doubt in this little scenario) you could not determine if that happens *before* the next iteration or just *after* all of them. The process of GarbageCollection is quite complex and in particual un-deterministic, so you can´t determine when *exactly* an instance is freed from memory.

Although you have three different instances of `FileOperations` which hold their own instances of `Obj1` and `Obj2` those instances may or may not remain on the heap, until GC finally decides to kick in. This happens at least when your app terminates, but usually far earlier. The only thing you *can* expect from GC is that it *will run*. The *eraliest* point for the GC to work on the other side is when an instance gets out of scope and no more references to that instance exist. In your case this is when an instance of `FileOperations` is not used any more in your code.

So you have more or less two options in your scenario:

1. GC working on every iteration or at least *some* of them, at least far earlier then your app terminates
2. when your app terminates

As your program is so little chances are very high that the second option happens. As an aside this improves overall performance, as GC does not need to work - or in particular free any instances - all the time, just a few (or in your case probably one) time(s).

Comment: I see... I had read that GC was un-deterministic, but I kind of took that to mean it will run when it gets the chance (like a low priority scheduled task), so in my real code each iteration lasts a few seconds - I had not appreciated it could just be held of "indefinitely" based on whatever rules c#/.net has. This is a good explanation thanks :)

Comment: Purely informational (for another reader and to illustrate your point) - I ran this with 10 iterations, now I see that the GC runs twice, once after around 7 iterations and once at the end... this is surprising to me, but as you say c#/.net probably thinks its more efficient to leave that allocation there since its harmless...  totally get it now (probably)

Answer (score -1):

GC does your clean up dont use finalizer you can use finalizer when you want implement idisposable pattern to your class and override dispose method i did it here in my github repo 
https://github.com/garapricot/MVCBookStore/blob/master/DAL/Services/BookService.cs

Comment: Thanks for that - I was not using or asking about destructors/finalizers - it was more about the GC destroying the objects (the ~Obj1() prints don't come from my code).